# Router authorizeStep from other app root keeps triggering

Tags: aurelia

My Aurelia project is split up in 2 app roots, both with their own route structure.
App root 1 contains all screens where you don't have to be authenticated (login, reset pwd,...) App root 2 all the other screens.

I'm blocking access to routes on app root 2 when you are not authenticated with an authorizeStep. In this step, I set the root to app root 1 when you are not authenticated. App root 1 has a login view as default route, so this works quite well. So, when you are not authenticated and try to navigate to a deep url in app root 2, this happens:

1. App Root 2 configures it's routes and tries to navigate to the deep url
2. The authorizeStep triggers, you are not authenticated, the route is cancelled and an aurelia.setRoot() happens to app root 1
3. App root 1 configures it's router and navigates you to the default route, the login page

The problem is manually logging out. When this button, residing in app root 2, is clicked. I clear user data, therefore you are not authenticated anymore. Following that step, I manually set the root to app root 1, and there I get an infinite loop:

1. App root 1 configures it's router and navigates you to the default route, the login page
2. The authorizeStep triggers from app root 2!, you are not authenticated, the route is cancelled and an aurelia.setRoot() happens to app root 1
3. App root 1 configures it's router and navigates you to the default route, the login page
4. ...

The problem is that the authorizeStep from root 2 triggers when navigating in root 1. I looked for a way for removing the authorizestep, but I don't think the framework currently exposes this. I find it very curious that this issue only occurs when clicking logout, deep linking and redirecting to login works as expected.

I created a reproducable gist for clarity, click the logout button and you will see the console infinitely repeating the authorizestep.

https://gist.run/?id=1a551dcc4bec7d191ab680a937b19cfc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to clear the steps yourself, this isn't done in a router.clear(), which the aurelia.setRoot() internally calls.

Fortunately you actually can do this yourself, with:
`this.pipelineProvider.reset();`

I don't find this behavior logical though, so I created an issue for it: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/465