# How to redirect to another router from an AuthorizedStep

Tags: aurelia

I have two routes — one is a public router and the other is the authorized router.

In my authorized router I have an authorizeStep.

The authorizedStep checks if there is a token in localStorage and if it is returns a next().

However if it fails to find a token its supposed to stop and jump out returning to the public router.

I am having trouble stopping the authorized step and instead going to the public router.

I have:

```
run(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any> {
      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => this.checkSessionExists(navigationInstruction, next)
        .then(result => result || next())
    );

 }
checkSessionExists(navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction, next: Next) {
    const session = this.authService.getIdentity();
    if (!session) {
    // HOW DO I CANCEL THE NEXT HERE AND GO TO THE PUBLIC ROUTER?
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('login'))
    }

    return next()

}

forceReturnToPublic() {
    this.authService.clearIdentity();
    this.router.navigate("/", { replace: true, trigger: false });
    this.router.reset();
    this.aurelia.setRoot("public/public/public");
}
```

I have the function forceReturnToPublic() however I want to go and cancel the next() then go directly to the other router... I dont want to redirect..

How do I cancel the next in the promise and reset the router?

Here is my boot.ts which should kick it back to public but I dont know how to jump out of the promise cleanly...

```
// After starting the aurelia, we can request the AuthService directly
// from the DI container on the aurelia object. We can then set the 
// correct root by querying the AuthService's checkJWTStatus() method
// to determine if the JWT exists and is valid.
aurelia.start().then(() => {
    var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
    let root: string = auth.checkJWTStatus() ? PLATFORM.moduleName('app/app/app') : PLATFORM.moduleName('public/public/public');

    aurelia.setRoot(root, document.body)
});
```

If I place the forceReturnToPublic() in place of the return next.cancel(new Redirect('login') it goes into and endless loop with errors.

**EDIT**

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956911/router-authorizestep-from-other-app-root-keeps-triggering?rq=1) question which indicates I should add "this.pipeLineProvider.reset()" so I did - like this...

```
forceReturnToPublic() {
    this.pipelineProvider.reset();
    this.authService.clearIdentity();
    this.router.navigate("/", { replace: true, trigger: false });
    this.router.reset();
    this.aurelia.setRoot("public/public/public");
}
```

Whilst it goes straight back to the public route I get an error in the console.

```
aurelia-logging-console.js:47 ERROR [app-router] Error: There was no router-view found in the view for ../components/clients/clientList/clientList.
at _loop (aurelia-router.js:281)
at NavigationInstruction._commitChanges (aurelia-router.js:307)
at CommitChangesStep.run (aurelia-router.js:143)
at next (aurelia-router.js:112)
at iterate (aurelia-router.js:1272)
at processActivatable (aurelia-router.js:1275)
at ActivateNextStep.run (aurelia-router.js:1161)
at next (aurelia-router.js:112)
at iterate (aurelia-router.js:1191)
at processDeactivatable (aurelia-router.js:1194)
```

I was clicking on the clientList nav link which does have a router-view..

How/where do I place the pipelineProvider.reset()? (if this is the problem)

But what I really want is...

How do I stop this router and cleanly move to the other router?

Answer (score 0):

As you do I keep trying things.. This worked for me as I believe the pipelineProvider needed to finish before moving to the next step.. So I used a promise like so:

```
forceReturnToPublic(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => this.pipelineProvider.reset())
        .then(() => this.authService.clearIdentity())
        .then(() => this.router.navigate("/", { replace: true, trigger: false }))
        .then(() => this.router.reset())
        .then(() => this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('public/public/public')));
}
```

...and no errors.